# Escaping Parentheses in Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

I have an ASP.Net website that allows you to export a Gridview to Excel. The Gridview has some column headings with words and then numbers surrounded by parentheses like this:

```
Abc<br>(43)
Xyz<br>(55)
```

I have set the bound field's HtmlEncode property to False because I do not want it to escape the line break tags I have in there. This is fine and I can even use `&amp;#40;` and `&amp;#41;` to escape the parentheses if I need to.

The issue I'm having is that Excel looks at the (43) as a negative number and displays it as -43. How can I escape the parentheses?

Comment: how does a negative number look in the html? and how does it come through in excel?

Comment: I was unable to fix this problem. I just ended up removing the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following `2 Lines` after "RenderControl" Line. It will resolve the issue.

```
string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
Response.Write(style);
```

Comment: Joe Philllips - I know it is too late but just for update, have you tried the above code? Just Add one line.